# How to fix data frame errors in a two way repeated measures ANOVA in R?

Tags: r

I want to do a two way repeated measures ANOVA, and I am new to R. My data does satisfy the conditions for the procedure and I am interested in doing if applicable a post hoc Tukey (I could do the two way repeated measures ANOVA effortlessly on excel but do not know how to to do it on R and cannot do Tukey on excel)

I have no idea what is wrong with my table as it is shown correctly formatted in the edit but posting is not.

Here is the data:

| ID | score | treatment | day |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 15 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 90 | 1 | 1 |
| 3 | 77 | 1 | 1 |
| 4 | 23 | 2 | 1 |
| 5 | 150 | 2 | 1 |
| 6 | 95 | 2 | 1 |
| 7 | 48 | 3 | 1 |
| 8 | 37 | 3 | 1 |
| 9 | 40 | 3 | 1 |
| 10 | 190 | 4 | 1 |
| 11 | 45 | 4 | 1 |
| 12 | 65 | 4 | 1 |
| 13 | 23 | 5 | 1 |
| 14 | 340 | 5 | 1 |
| 15 | 44 | 5 | 1 |
| 1 | 34 | 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 190 | 1 | 2 |
| 3 | 80 | 1 | 2 |
| 4 | 17 | 2 | 2 |
| 5 | 55 | 2 | 2 |
| 6 | 56 | 2 | 2 |
| 7 | 33 | 3 | 2 |
| 8 | 7 | 3 | 2 |
| 9 | 76 | 3 | 2 |
| 10 | 3 | 4 | 2 |
| 11 | 8 | 4 | 2 |
| 12 | 500 | 4 | 2 |
| 13 | 78 | 5 | 2 |
| 14 | 90 | 5 | 2 |
| 15 | 88 | 5 | 2 |

[first half of table since it is not formatting correctly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4EP1c.jpg)

[second half of table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rqzoh.jpg)

I have tried the following code:

```
library(readr)
data <- read.csv(file = "sampleData.csv", header = TRUE)  #I have also tried without header = TRUE
data$treatment = as.factor(data$treatment) #treatment is independent categorical variable
data$day = as.factor(data$day) #day is independent categorical variable
data$ID = as.factor(data$ID) #so ID is not treated as a variable
attach(data)
twoWayA <- aov(ID ~ treatment*day + Error(score/(treatment*day)))
summary(twoWayA)
```

that gives me the following error:

> Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, ID, value = integer(0)) :
> replacement has 0 rows, data has 64

My original data did not have the ID column and used this:

```
library(readr)
data <- read.csv(file = "No ID sampleData.csv", header = TRUE) #I have also tried without header = TRUE

data$treatment = as.factor(data$treatment) #treatment is independent categorical variable
data$day = as.factor(data$day) #day is independent categorical variable
attach(data)
twoWayA <- aov(score ~ treatment*day + Error(score/(treatment*day)))
summary(twoWayA)
```

this gave me the following error:

> Error in eval(predvars, data, env) : object 'score' not found

Comment: I created your table manually using your images and the code worked fine. The first error you're getting is saying ID has 0 rows. Is it blank in the file or something?

Comment: use `dput(data)` to share objects on SO easily; also you should avoid using `attach` instead use `aov(formula, data = data)`

Comment: Thanks @mark_1985 for fixing it, no it is not blank, I tried this twice, one with an column for ID and one without (both had same scores, treatment, and day) and got the errors

Comment: Hi @rawr I just tried your suggestion and got the following error: Error: object of type 'closure' is not subsettable

Comment: whoops meant @rawr thank you for fixing my question, sorry

Comment: the second formula works fine for me with your example although you have the same variable on both sides of the equation so you should address that. the first formula doesn't make sense, why would your outcome be the ID variable? for an anova it should be some numeric variable like score

Comment: @rawr the reason why was because I thought I was doing the two way repeated measures ANOVA incorrectly, since on excel I am getting different values and I am doing it on R because I need to do a post hoc Tukey after doing the ANOVA.

Comment: Are your columns named correctly? Also, you don't have your data argument in the `aov()` function. This might have been mentioned by @rawr. It would also be useful is you shared the results you got from excel, if you know that they are correct so we can compare the results from R. @ineedhelp

Answer (score 1):

So just to clarify a two-way ANOVA, or really an ANOVA in general, is used to find out if the means of two groups are statistically different from one another.

They usually have some sort of **numerical outcome**, or **dependent variable**, and a **categorical input** or **independent variable**.

Due to this **I highly doubt you should use patient ID as the outcome**, as that would not give you any inference on whether the group means are statistically different from one another.

My supposition is that the score is the outcome and that the treatment and day are the inputs.

Due to this I believe that the formula should be as follows

```
dat <- data.frame(ID = rep(1:15, 2), score = c(rnorm(30, 40, 5)), treatment = rep(rep(1:5, each = 3), 2), day = rep(1:2, each = 15))


dat$treatment <- as.factor(dat$treatment)
dat$day <- as.factor(dat$day)


twoWayA <- aov(score ~ treatment*day + Error(ID/(treatment*day)), data = dat)
summary(twoWayA)
```

The above threw no errors for me, and it shouldn't for you either as long as your dataset is the same as shown in the original question.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but for some reason I do get errors. I get the following error: Error in terms.formula(formula, "Error", data = data) : 
object 'dat' not found


Additionally, (I am using RStudio) it keeps converting ID into ï...ID?

Comment: when changing data= data, I got an error but also got the ANOVA output.

Warning in aov(score ~ treatment * day + Error(ï..ID/(treatment * day)), data = data) :
  Error() model is singular

Comment: Not sure about the ID column name issue, but I would suggest wrapping it in backticks ``` so there aren't any issues. As far as Error() model is singular, you are only supposed to use **within** subject conditions in an Error() term. Not sure how your study/experiment was set-up, nor do I have access to your whole dataset so I can't consult any further unfortunately.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply, I will try the backticks and the odd thing about the error() is that ANOVA works although incorrectly. I am not sure if I used between rather than within inadvertently in my code. I will look at it again

Answer (score -1):

It seems you have both a between subject factor (treatment) and one within subject factor (day).
I think you should use treatment as fixed effect in your equation and day as random.
Treatment is fixed because each patients received either treatment 1 or treatment 2 (ect..) but not both.

2 options are possible to deal with your data:

1. Do a linear mixed model with a random effect for days:

`m<-lme(score~day*treatment,random=~id|day)`

2. Do a mixed anova

`res.aov <- anova_test( data = data, dv = score, wid = id, between = treatment, within = time ) get_anova_table(res.aov)`

OR

`m<-aov(score~time*treatment+Error(id|time)`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).